# How to recursively download xsd schema files

Tags: .net, xml, xsd

I am using xsd.exe to create .net classes from a vendor's published schemas.  For some reason, it doesn't allow me to specify the URL of the schema on the command line.  Okay that's lame, but fine, so I download it to the local folder and run it, but there are several xsd:include statements which reference other xsd files at a relative location, which in turn reference still more xsd files.  The include statements look like this:

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="otherstuff.xsd"/>
```

So if I visit each URL for each xsd file one-at-a-time and download them to my local file system, the xsd.exe class creation works, but this is a real pain and I can't help but feel there has got to be a better way.  Is there some functionality to xsd.exe that I am missing, or is there some other method/tool I can use to download an xsd schema and all the referenced xsd files?